# JSON Parse error when reading json object from file

Tags: c++, json, ubuntu, crash

Observing random crash when reading JSON file data to a JSON object.
Here is the summary of the crash.
The crash point is always consistent.

Description:

One process takes care of the following:

1. [Library Call] --> Returns serialised JSON key-value pair as char *, which is placed
   in std::string
   Example : `std:string testString = libCall();`
   testString now holds a string like this {"IS_JSON_FLAGON": true}
2. To ensure there are no additional characters and to adhere to the JSON object
   compatibility, the std::string is parsed and then assigned to a JSON object

Example:    `nlohmann::json jWriteObj = nlohmann::json::parse(testString .c_str());`

3. The JSON object is then written to JSON file

Example :

```
    mutex mLock; //global variable 
    upDateFlagsFile()
    {
        fstream fileDesc;
        mLock.lock();
        fileDesc.open(<filepath>, trunc mode);
        fileDesc << jWriteObj;
        fileDesc.close();
        mLock.unlock();
    }
```

this creates/updates the file with .json extension
Example: flagsFile.json with data {"IS_JSON_FLAGON":true}

In another process, the file written by the previous process is read

1. Modules want to know the Flag value, so calls isFlagOn("IS_JSON_FLAGON")
   which then opens the file and reads the data to a json object

   Example:  [Module reading the flag value] ---->isFlagOn("IS_JSON_FLAGON")
   definition for isFlagOn()

```
    extern mutex mLock; //using the same lock for read and write
    isFlagOn(char* flagName)
    {
       istream fileDesc;
       bool flagValue = false; 
       nlohmann::json jReadObj;
    try{
       mLock.lock();   
       fileDesc.open();
       fileDesc >> jReadObj; //  ---> Crash occurs randomly at this line
       flagValue = jReadObj[flagName].get<bool>();
       fileDesc.close();
       mLock.unlock();
      }
       catch(nlohmann::json::exception &e)
       {
           std:cout<< "Exception caught";
       }
       return flagValue;
    }
```

The crash is very random on Ubuntu 20.04 and points to the line highlighted.
The surprising part is the exception is not getting caught inspite of using the wildcard exception approach
Any suggestions on what needs to be corrected in this would help.

Comment: You haven't provided enough code but my _guess_ is that you are writing to the file in one process while reading it from another process. You haven't showed how you sync the processes. If this is really the case: When you write to the file, write to a temporary file (in the same directory) instead and when that is done and the temporary file is closed, rename the temporary file to the target name.

Comment: "_The surprising part is the exception is not getting caught inspite of using the wildcard exception approach_" - No, that's not surprising. If the program has UB _anything_ can happen. Catching soft exceptions is only guaranteed to work if your program is well behaved.

Comment: Another note: The thread synchronization: `mutex mLock; mLock.lock();` won't help to protect the section below. Every call to `upDateFlagsFile` will create a new `mutex` and successfully lock it - even if many threads calls the function at the same time. Oh, and in case you think the `mutex` helps to synchronize access between **processes**: It does not.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Based on your comments, made edits to my question. I hope I am clear now.
The file reads and writes are synchronized using the mutex shared across the process.

Comment: "_using the mutex shared across the process_" - How? I've never heard of anyone (successfully) sharing mutexes between processes. `std::mutex`es can be shared among **threads** in the **same** process. How many processes are involved? One or more? You say "_In another process, the file written_".

Comment: If you need mutexes across processes you can use https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_77_0/doc/html/interprocess/synchronization_mechanisms.html#interprocess.synchronization_mechanisms.mutexes.mutexes_interprocess_mutexes